# SQL Server error: Cannot drop the user because it does not exist or you do not have permission

Tags: sql-server

I got this error after creating a few SQL Server logins and users. I could not delete one particular user. I was getting the above error when trying to delete it, and I was getting a message that this user already exists when trying to create it. Catch 22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A closer look at the users returned by:

```
SELECT * FROM SYSUSERS
```

showed that my existing/non-existing user was really a role - the *issqlrole* was set to 1. Here is the fix:

```
DROP ROLE myuser
```

Answer (score 2):

I was running into a similar problem. My problem was that the user was created while in a specific database, but the Delete User step was performed in master.

The create script

```
USE DbName;CREATE LOGIN LoginName WITH PASSWORD = 'Password';
```

But the delete script (executed in master db)

```
DROP USER LoginName
```

The moment I added the USE to the delete script everything worked as planned.

```
USE DbName;DROP USER LoginName
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. In my case I was using the SSMS on jump server to drop the user on a remote server.

Then I logged into the server directly and was able to drop the user.